# MVC.Net HTML Encoding, IE7 vs other browsers

Tags: urlencode, html-encode

When I have this in my view

```
<a href="../Product/Category/<%= Html.Encode(item.Category) %>/Default.aspx?partial=False">
    <%= Html.Encode(item.Category)%></a>
```

It renders as expected in IE8 & FF

```
<a href="../Product/Category/Sauces%20&amp;%20Toppings/Default.aspx?partial=False">
    Sauces &amp; Toppings</a>
```

but does not render correctly in IE7

```
<a href="../Allergen/Category/Sauces &amp; Toppings/Default.aspx?partial=False">
    Sauces &amp; Toppings</a>
```

Specifically, it appers IE7 is decoding the href property value.

**How do I get IE7 to render the encoded href?**

Comment: IE doesn't have anything to do with the rendering. :) The problem is that the URL is malformed - HTML encoded instead of URL encoded.

Comment: Make this an answer instead of a comment and I'll except it.

Comment: No need - SLaks fixed it for ya.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong encoding.

You need to call `Html.AttributeEncode(Url.Encode(item.Category))`.